# Counting the ID and assigning a Year

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, sas, sas-studio

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data have;
input ID P1 P2 P3 P4;
datalines;

ID    P1    P2    P3    P4
12    10    15    20    30
12    -     20    5     3
12    -     -     25    33
12    -     -     -     30
19    10    15    20    30
19    -     10    17    30
19    -     -     5     30
19    -     -     -     30
;
run;
```

I am trying to build in a variable called Year which then can be used to identify that the ID and P1-P4 is an array with each row representing a year. Such that the dataset would look like.

```
data want;
set have;
input ID P1 P2 P3 P4;
datalines;

ID    P1    P2    P3    P4 Year
12    10    15    20    30 2017
12    -     20    5     3  2018
12    -     -     25    33 2019
12    -     -     -     30 2020
19    10    15    20    30 2017
19    -     10    17    30 2018
19    -     -     5     30 2019
19    -     -     -     30 2020
;
run;
```

I originally used to use this code:

```
Data Year;
    do ID = 1 to 8;
        do Year = 2017 to 2020;
        output;
        end;
    end;
run;

data Final;
set have;
Merge Year;
run;
```

But now that I am working with a different dataset each time and I don't know the structure of the ID, I can't keep changing ID=1 to 8 to suit the dataset each time.

My question: Is there a way to do this through the dataset, possibly a count?

```
Count ID = 2017;
Year = count + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a second data set that will be merged with the first.

You do need to make assumptions about the grouping in the `have` data set.  The assumptions are the data is already sorted or arranged in a manner that allows a monotonic year value to be assigned to each sequential row in each group.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id 
    then year = 2017; %* initial year for a group;
    else year + 1; %* increment year for subsequent rows of a group;
run;
```

Comment: Smart, I'll try that now